# anomaly while exporting openGL texture using openCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, opengl

For debugging purpose I decided to write texture exporting function:

```py
def image_export(self, file_name: str):
    im_format = file_name.rsplit('.')[-1]
    if im_format in ('jpg',):
        iformat = gl.GL_BGR
    elif im_format in ('png',):
        iformat = gl.GL_BGRA
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError

    with self: # binding texture
        # gl.glPixelStorei(gl.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
        im = (gl.glGetTexImage(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, iformat, gl.GL_FLOAT) * 255).astype('uint8')

    im = np.flip(im, axis=0)
    cv2.imwrite(file_name, im)
```

Tested with 500x500 texture and works fine: 
[image: good result]

But when I try 500x600 thing goes strange:
[image: bad result]

I have to reshape it to get desired image:

```py
    # ...
    im = im.reshape((600, 500, 3)) # added line
    im = np.flip(im, axis=0)
    cv2.imwrite(file_name, im)
```

Which then results in: 
[image: fixed result]

Recently I've asked question [glTexImage2D data not filled as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221801/glteximage2d-data-not-filled-as-expected)
so I tried `gl.glPixelStorei(gl.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)`, but didnt found it effecting anything.
Reshaping doesn't make sense. Without reshaping, I should simply get 90 degree rotated image. What am I not understanding?

ADDITION:
After reading the comment, tried to summarize my understanding. Can you(someone) verify my conclusion?

[image: my understanding]

Comment: I didn't post a comment, but  full answer. There is nothing complicated about that. PyOpenGL returns shape information in the form (w, h, c), but NumPy expects (h, w, c). The pixels of the image are stored linearly. The order does not need to be changed, but how they are interpreted must be changed.

Comment: I think your first comment says what I'm saying at the bottom right comment of the last picture '...(array) pixel index doesn't represent its position in texture' right? But if so, that leaves why implementation does that. It could simply match array index with texture pixel coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) is not the same as [`transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html). `reshape` does not change the axis (and thus not rotate) but it changes the shape (width and height) of the array.

e.g.:

```py
a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                 [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

```py
ar = a.reshape((4, 2))
print(ar)
```

reshape:

> ```
> [[1 2]
>  [3 4]
>  [5 6]
>  [7 8]]
> ```

transpose:

```py
at = a.transpose((1, 0))
print(at)
```

> ```
> [[1 5]
>  [2 6]
>  [3 7]
>  [4 8]]
> ```

---

[`glGetTexImage`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glGetTexImage.html) returns an array with the shape (*width*, *height*, *channels*). This means the shape of an RGB 200x100 image is (200, 100, 3). You can verify this with `print(im.shape)`.

However the [`numpy.ndarray.shape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) is specified in row major order (*rows*, *columns*). This means the shape of the [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

> ```py
> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
>              [5, 6, 7, 8]])
> ```

is **not** (4, 2) but (2, 4).

The shape of an array that represents a RGB 4x2 image

```py
a = np.array(
   [[(r1, g1, b1), (r2, g2, b2), (r3, g3, b3), (r4, g4, b4)],
    [(r5, g5, b5), (r6, g6, b6), (r7, g7, b7), (r8, g8, b8)]])
```

is (2, 4, 3).

PyOpenGL and NumPy (cv2) interpret the shape differently. Therefore you must change the shape and `reshape` the array:

```py
im = im.reshape((im.shape[1], im.shape[0], im.shape[2]))
```

---

Summarize: There is nothing complicated about that. PyOpenGL returns shape information in the form (w, h, c), but NumPy expects (h, w, c). The pixels of the image are stored linearly. The order does not need to be changed, but how they are interpreted must be changed.